# Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

i need to create a custom validate in angular 7 .

write this code :

```
CheckUserNameExisit(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
 console.log('in functions')
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  var userService = new UserService(httpClient);
  let usernameExist: Usernameexist;
  usernameExist = userService.InitialUserNameExist();
  usernameExist.UserName = control.value;
  console.log(usernameExist.UserName)
  userService.checkUsername(usernameExist)
    .subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success == false) {
        console.log(data.success)
        resolve({ 'usernameExists': false });
      } else {
        console.log(true)
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
});
}
```

and this is `UserSerivce` :

```
checkUsername(item: Usernameexist): Observable<GenericModel<Usermodel>> {
  console.log('go')
  return this.httpClient.post<GenericModel<Usermodel>>('https://localhost:44372/api/v1/User/FindbyName/', item);
}
```

but when i need to use this validation it show me this error :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>       at UserService.push../src/app/services/user.service.ts.UserService.checkUsername

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ??**

Comment: A lot of things going wrong here. Don't take it the wrong way, but I suggest a strong read into javascript/typescript first, and after that read the guides listed in [angular.io](https://angular.io), and after that read about rxjs, and after that, start with your first real project

Answer (score 0):

In **userservice**, inject Httpclient

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not added `HTTPClientModule`. [As Angular documentation says:](https://angular.io/guide/http#!#http-providers)

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and yourservice.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```